# PHP RegEx won't pick up question mark

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to match urls in a string using the PHP function "preg_match_all". It works fine, except it will not match urls with question marks in them.

For example, this will match fine:

```
http://espn.com/mlb
```

But this will not match:

```
http://espn.com/mlb?player=71
```

Here is the regex I am using,

```
$regexUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
```

I cannot figure out why the question mark is not being picked up by the \S. I've tried a lot of different expressions and cannot get the question mark to match. Any ideas?

EDIT:

It turns out preg_match_all was returning true, but I was not escaping the question mark in the preg_match_all output, so the preg_replace call that I was making later on was failing.

Comment: If you use a different regex delimiter, you won't have to escape all the forward slashes, eg `$regex = '@pattern/with/forward/slashes@i'`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works but question marks are still not matching.

Comment: @Phil, while PHP's PCRE implementation definitely has that capability, I tend to prefer (and push in my company for standardizing on) the slash delimiter for readability/discoverability during collaboration and maintenance. The slash delimiter is instantly recognizable as a regex, and the trouble of escaping slashes is minimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question mark means that the preceding match is optional, i.e.

```
/https?/
```

will cause both "http" and "https" to match. You must escape the question mark to match it.

For example:

```
/https\?/
```

will now only match "https?".

Comment: Reread the question, for some reason question marks aren't being matched by the \S at the end of the expression, thats the problem.

Comment: Apologies, though now I'm curious what you mean by "will not match". Do you mean that `preg_match_all` is not returning `TRUE` for a match, or that the (optional) `$matches` argument does not show the portion of the string that matches the subpattern `(\/\S*)`? **EDIT**: on my machine with PHP 5.3.8 `preg_match_all` both returns `TRUE` and the `$matches` argument shows the expected results. Output: http://pastie.org/private/nk9xv9kb2aadyjtsgcdq

Comment: I actually am going to give you credit for solving this cause your question led to me figuring this out. Preg_match_all was returning true. But I was not escaping the question mark when calling preg_replace later on.