# preg_replace string with (?)

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a set of string and want to replace

```
/church-ceremony-venues/all/in-quezon-city/church?page=2
```

to

```
/church-ceremony-venues/all/in-quezon-city?page=2
```

I try to follow answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116505/php-regex-wont-pick-up-question-mark) but nothing happens.

Comment: Simply this: `str_replace('/church?', '?', $str);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = "/church-ceremony-venues/all/in-quezon-city/church?page=2";
echo preg_replace("/\/church\?/", "?", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

get all characters before the last `/` and after the `?`, then you have your new string with the captured group `$1` and `$2`

```
$input_lines = "/church-ceremony-venues/all/in-quezon-city/church?page=2";

echo preg_replace("/.([^\?]+)\/.+(\?.+)/", "/$1$2", $input_lines);
```

look example at [php live regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/4WN)